# Port-forward drops connection to pod after first connection

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubectl, amazon-eks, rhel

Doing port forward for postgresql database through service : `nohup kubectl --namespace test-0 port-forward service/operational-db 60000:5432 > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Port-forward seems to be working till there is no connection from host machine. The moment Host machine tries to connect for the first time it throws this error -

> E0717 11:57:36.623431   15244 portforward.go:407] an error occurred
> forwarding 60000 -> 5432: error forwarding port 5432 to pod
> a2f34569140ff7aa7079e06aedca300e8776cb9a5b06806ed04fcf0feba018e8, uid
> : failed to execute portforward in network namespace
> "/var/run/netns/cni-6db2a2b7-68be-dade-ada5-32e00597e921": read tcp4
> 127.0.0.1:48064->127.0.0.1:5432: read: connection reset by peer

**kubectl/server version :**

```
> Client Version: v1.26.1 Kustomize Version: v4.5.7 Server Version:
> v1.24.14-eks-c12679a
```

Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That error means that the port to which you're trying to connect isn't actually listening. This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- e.g., your pod/deployment and service manifests that would allow us to reproduce the problem locally. Is the database pod up and running? Is the service selector using the appropriate labels? We need more information.

Comment: If you're only seeing this after the connection has been idle for several minutes, this generally matches behavior I've seen and I don't think it's unexpected.  If you need a long-lived connection to something in Kubernetes, a Service will usually be a better choice than a port-forward.  (Though publicly exposing a database is often considered inadvisable.)

Comment: it comes out to be incompatibility of kubectl version to server side version.... however it could be having some more issue specific to SSL connection to postgresql with forwarded port however I am yet to conclude on that... but when downgraded to compatible version then non-ssl connection seems to be working without any further issue....

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue with my setup... looks like kubectl version is not compatible with server version.... So downgraded to v1.21.2 then it worked without any issue...  Key take away here is to first check the kubectl version & server side version to understand the compatibility... this issue creates lot of confusion due multiple explanation available on github.... e.g. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1169#issuecomment-1165140134

```
Downgraded from Client Version: v1.26.1 to Client Version: v1.21.2
```